# Isomorphism into $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I came across this lemma and its proof but am having a hard time understanding why such a $\phi$ must be an isomorphism into $\mathbb{C}$. The proof follows by constructing the isomorphism $\phi$, but I can't understand why it is surjective. In fact, I have a suspicion that it isn't surjective, and that in this case the author meant monomorphism rather than isomorphism. I have a vague memory of an old text using this as notation?

Any guidance would be appreciated. The lemma and its proof are below.

**Lemma.** Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, $\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{m}$ are in $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathcal{F}_{1} = \mathcal{F}(\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{m})$. Then either $\mathcal{F}_{1} = \mathcal{F}$, or there is an isomorphism $\phi$ of $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ into $\Bbb C$ that fixes every element of $\mathcal{F}$ but moves at least one $\xi_{i}$.

PROOF:
Assume $\mathcal{F}_{1} \neq \mathcal{F}$. Then there is a nonempty subset of ${\xi_{1},\dots,\xi{m}}$, say $(\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{j})$ (after reordering) that is minimal with respect to the property
\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{F}_{1} = \mathcal{F}(\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{j}).
\end{equation*}
Put $\mathcal{F}_{2} = \mathcal{F}(\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{j-1})$. (This is $\mathcal{F}$ when $j$ = 1.) Then
\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{F}_{2} \subsetneqq \mathcal{F}_{2}(\xi_{j}) = \mathcal{F}_{1}.
\end{equation*}

Let $\phi$ fix every element of $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ and choose $\phi(\xi_{j})$ as follows:
If $\xi_{j}$ is transcendental over $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, let $\phi(\xi_{j})$ be any complex number $\neq \xi_{j}$ that is also transcendental over $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ (such as 1 + $\xi_{j}$).
If $\xi_{j}$ is algebraic over $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, with minimal polynomial $p(x)$, let $\phi(\xi_{j})$ be another root of $p(x)$.
To every $w$ in $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ corresponds a rational function $r$, with coefficients in $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, such that $w = r(\xi_{j})$. Setting $\phi(w) = r(\phi(\xi_{j}))$ gives the desired isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, this isomorphism will not (usually) be surjective.  I think that this is usually the case when people use the terminology "isomorphism $\dots$ into".  In contrast, "isomorphism $\dots$ to" usually indicates surjectivity (and of course "isomorphism $\dots$ onto" always does).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Cleared things up quite easily!